# System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException Convert

Tags: c#

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Conversion failed when converting
>   the varchar value 'System.Data.DataRowView' to data type int.

How to convert?

```
public partial class FrmItems : MaterialSkin.Controls.MaterialForm
{
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=G:\Users\Admin\source\repos\Elektrokalkulace\Sklad.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30");
    SqlDataAdapter dt;
    DataTable dtCategories = new DataTable();
    DataTable dtSubCategories = new DataTable();
    DataTable dtItems = new DataTable();

    public FrmItems()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        dt = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM Categories", conn);
        dt.Fill(dtCategories);
        CbxCat.DataSource = dtCategories;
        CbxCat.DisplayMember = "NameCat";
        CbxCat.ValueMember = "CatId";

        var skinManager = MaterialSkinManager.Instance;
        skinManager.AddFormToManage(this);
        skinManager.Theme = MaterialSkinManager.Themes.DARK;
        skinManager.ColorScheme = new ColorScheme(Primary.BlueGrey800, Primary.BlueGrey900, Primary.BlueGrey500, Accent.LightBlue200, TextShade.WHITE);

    }
    private void FrmItems_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // TODO: Tento řádek načte data do tabulky 'skladDataSet.Items'. Můžete jej přesunout nebo jej odstranit podle potřeby.
        this.itemsTableAdapter.Fill(this.skladDataSet.Items);
    } 

    private void CbxCat_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dtSubCategories.Clear();
        dt = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM Subcategories WHERE CatId='"+ CbxCat.SelectedValue +"'", conn);
        dt.Fill(dtSubCategories);
        CbxSubcat.DataSource = dtSubCategories;
        CbxSubcat.DisplayMember = "NameSubCat";
        CbxSubcat.ValueMember = "SubCatId";
    }

    private void CbxSubcat_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dtItems.Clear();
        dt = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM Items WHERE SubCatId='" + CbxSubcat.SelectedValue + "'", conn);
        dt.Fill(dtItems);
        dataGridViewItem.DataSource = dtItems;
    }

    private void pictureBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        FrmHlavniMenu menu = new FrmHlavniMenu();
        menu.Show();
        this.Hide();
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you share full stack trace of exception?

Comment: which line throws the error?

Comment: dt.Fill(dtSubCategories);

Comment: Of course, if I change the Primary Key from int to varchar in the database, it will work. But my intention is to keep the Primary Key as an int and the Foreign Key as an int

Comment: For someone easy, but I only program the first month. I am a beginner.

Answer (score 0):

You claim it is failing on the second line below?

```
dt = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM Subcategories WHERE CatId='"+ CbxCat.SelectedValue +"'", conn);
dt.Fill(dtSubCategories);
```

If CatId is an INT then this will fail because of the apostrophes (') surrounding the value. And please use parameters:

```
dt = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM Subcategories WHERE CatId = @CatId", conn);
dt.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CatId", CbxCat.SelectedValue);
dt.Fill(dtSubCategories);
```

Secondly, what is the type of `CbxCat.SelectedValue`? If it returns a string then you will need to parse the value as an integer: `int.Parse(CbxCat.SelectedValue)`

But the exception suggests it is actually of type `System.Data.DataRowView`. In that case you need to access the the `item` property, for example, `CbxCat.SelectedValue["CategoryId"]`

See for more info on DataRowView:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datarowview.item?view=netframework-4.8#System_Data_DataRowView_Item_System_String_

Comment: Thank you for your help, writes "System.ArgumentException: There is no mapping from a System.Data.DataRowView type object to a known native type managed provider."

Comment: @pokerista yes - you're not parsing the value correctly. Try use: `CbxCat.Text`. I.e. `int.Parse(CbxCat.Text)`

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved it this way. It took me a lot of effort, but it was worth it. Thank you all for your support and thank you very very much.

enter code here

```
public partial class FrmItems : MaterialSkin.Controls.MaterialForm
{
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=G:\Users\Admin\source\repos\Elektrokalkulace\Stock.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30");

    int CatId;

    public FrmItems()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        refreshCat();

        var skinManager = MaterialSkinManager.Instance;
        skinManager.AddFormToManage(this);
        skinManager.Theme = MaterialSkinManager.Themes.DARK;
        skinManager.ColorScheme = new ColorScheme(Primary.BlueGrey800, Primary.BlueGrey900, Primary.BlueGrey500, Accent.LightBlue200, TextShade.WHITE);

    }
    private void FrmItems_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
    private void refreshCat()
    {
        conn.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Categories", conn);
        SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        sda.Fill(dt);
        conn.Close();
        CbxCat.DisplayMember = "NameCat";
        CbxCat.ValueMember = "CatId";
        CbxCat.DataSource = dt;
    }


    private void CbxCat_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (CbxCat.SelectedValue.ToString() != null)
        {
            CatId = Convert.ToInt32(CbxCat.SelectedValue.ToString());

            refreshSubcat(CatId);
        }
    }

    private void refreshSubcat(int CatId)
    {
        conn.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Subcategories WHERE CatId=@CatId", conn);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("CatId", CatId);
        SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        sda.Fill(dt);
        conn.Close();
        CbxSubcat.DisplayMember = "NameSubcat";
        CbxSubcat.ValueMember = "SubcatId";
        CbxSubcat.DataSource = dt;
    }   
    private void CbxSubcat_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        conn.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Items WHERE SubCatId='" + CbxSubcat.SelectedValue + "'", conn);
        SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        sda.Fill(dt);
        conn.Close();
        dataGridViewItem.DataSource = dt;

    }


    private void pictureBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        FrmMainMenu menu = new FrmMainMenu();
        menu.Show();
        this.Hide();
    }
}
enter code here
```